# Fail to add ODBC Data Source to a SQL Server

Tags: sql, jdbc, odbc

I use an online database which I am able to connect through altium or dbVisulizer. I want to add an instance to that database using ODBC Data source in windows, but it fails. The steps I followed are pictured below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea why is this happening?

Additional information:

1. Altium use the following information: `ConnectionString = Provider=SQLNCLI11.1; User ID=alib_WFC5AKIMTQCL; Password="*********"; Initial Catalog=altium_library; Data Source=db.altiumlibrary.com,1433; Initial File Name=""; Server SPN=""`
2. After connecting through dbVisulizer I have the following information: `The server version is: Microsoft SQL Server 14.00.2027 Microsoft JDBC Driver 9.2 for SQL Server 9.2.1.0`

Comment: You followed something like this: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/access-jdbc-dbv.rst ?  Where are you stuck?  What do you need help with?

Comment: I want to access the JDBC database from MS Access. I want to add the database in ODBC Data Source, but it seems that I need a driver

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. However, in most cases, if you can connect to sql server via jdbc drivers, then you can connect to the same sql server with odbc.

Access does not support jdbc, and in most cases that driver is Java, and thus you would be talking about a java enabled client side software.

For example, I have a instance of SQL server. I direct connect from Access over the network to SQL server - using ODBC drivers.

However, my android phone? Well, I use jdbc type 4 drivers, and thus my android phone can also direct connect to that same instance of sql server on the network.

However, there is no support for Access to connect to SQL server using jdbc drivers, but then again, if that is SQL server in question, then both jdbc, and odbc should be able to connect to that running instance of SQL server.

Now, you might be able to setup and run what is called a jdbc "bridge" connection. This would require that you install + setup a bridge on your computer. (and that bridge runs like a mini web server - it is NOT just a driver, but a web like "service"/"server" that you have to have running. In fact, it quite much the reverse that such a bridge is for. So, for example, if you running that bridge, then it would be possible for jdbc drivers to in fact connect to the access database (this would be a type 2 (or 3???) jdbc driver/connection.

So, to be clear, a jdbc type 4 connection is NOT possible to Access, since they require a so called "socket" (tc/ip) connection. Access is file based, so you don't ever connect to a access database, but you OPEN IT as a file. However, as noted, you are talking about Access connecting to the server anyway.

However, Access does not support, nor use nor have any means to use and consume a jdbc driver. But then again, it stands to reason that any database from MySQL, Oracle, PostgrSQL, SQL server, and more ALL HAVE ODBC drivers.

So it begs the question, why a ODBC driver would not be used here?

But, as noted, since Access supports ODBC drivers, and not jdbc drivers, then the answer is no - Access cannot use such drivers.

Comment: I see clear now. My question should be why can not connect to SQL Server using ODBC? I will come up with an edit

Comment: Yes, you shoud be able to connect to sql server. The issue/problem is where does the SQL server reside? At company network, in the cloud? Where? If the sql server is on your company network, then internal you can and should be able to connect. If you are outside at home or on the road, then you need a VPN to be setup, and again you can and should be able to connect.

Comment: Can you see my problem now?

Comment: You can't just point your connection to say amazon web site and expect the wild and crazy internet to by pass the web site and connect to their database, can you? Unless that SQL server allows external connections on that web site, then as  general rule you can't direct connect to the database unless they opened up and allow direct connections to that web site. In most cases, the web site is 100% free with code behind to connect to the given database. Allowing external connections to database tends to be locked down. So this depends on the server setup and connections you have and are allowed

Comment: So you either need a VPN, or have to work with the web provider to see if they allow external connections to the database (most don't, since it is a huge security risk). If the web server is on your own network - then no problem. So this comes down to the web server setup, and what kind of connections they allow, or you are able to allow and setup if this is your own web server that you run. I would think that allowing anyone with Access to just simple connect to that web database is going to be a huge security hole the size of a wide open barn door, right?

Comment: I mean, even if you can open up the database ports, do you really want to do that? last time I did that (16 years ago), within less then 20 minutes, I looked at the SQL server logs, and "bots" were already trying to logon with "User:Admin, pass=Admin", and then "User:SA, pass=12345678 etc. So, this then comes down to what kind of security is in place, and will simple external logons and connections be allowed to anyone with Access then?

Comment: I have access, I have id and password. Its an open database. As I already mention, I can visualize the tables using DbVisulizer or Altium. My goal is to add the connection to that database in ODBC Data Source to be able to visualize tables using Access

Comment: Ok, then it should be possible. I would try with sql server studio, and see if that connects. But if those other tools can connect using ODBC, then Access should be able to connect also. I would first try a FILE dsn. If that does not work, then try using a system dsn - but either should work.